# How to DRY repeating block lists in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following configuration and I would like to avoid the repetition of `registrant_contact`, `admin_contact` and `tech_contact`. How can I make this configuration shorter? I have multiple domains and the same block list repeats in the configuration file again and again:

```
locals {
  contact = {
    address_line_1 = "Berlin"
    city           = "Berlin"
    contact_type   = "PERSON"
    country_code   = "DE"
    email          = var.aws_billing_mails[0]
    first_name     = "Foo"
    last_name      = "Bar"
    zip_code       = "12345"
    phone_number   = "+49.123456789"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53domains_registered_domain" "my_domain" {
  domain_name        = "mydomain.com"
  auto_renew         = true
  transfer_lock      = true
  registrant_privacy = true
  admin_privacy      = true
  tech_privacy       = true

  registrant_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }

  admin_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }

  tech_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }
}

resource "aws_route53domains_registered_domain" "my_other_domain" {
  domain_name        = "myotherdomain.com"
  auto_renew         = true
  transfer_lock      = true
  registrant_privacy = true
  admin_privacy      = true
  tech_privacy       = true

  registrant_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }

  admin_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }

  tech_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to how the provider models this resource type, this isn't actually "repetition" as far as Terraform is concerned: the provider declares three distinct block types and so Terraform treats them all as separate types even though they happen to have identical arguments defined inside.

Comment: To allow consolidating this further the provider schema would need to change to have e.g. a single block type called `contact` which has an argument inside that decides which kind of contact it is, or a single argument called `contacts` which takes a mapping from contact types to contact objects.

Comment: This isn't something you'll be able to change from within your module though; this is part of the provider's API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about the blocks, but you can reduce the **number of resources**. So instead of having two `aws_route53domains_registered_domain`, you can have only one, with the help of `for_each`. For example:

```
locals {
 contact = {
    "mydomain.com" = {
        address_line_1 = "Berlin"
        city           = "Berlin"
        contact_type   = "PERSON"
        country_code   = "DE"
        email          = var.aws_billing_mails[0]
        first_name     = "Foo"
        last_name      = "Bar"
        zip_code       = "12345"
        phone_number   = "+49.123456789"
    },
    
    "myotherdomain.com" = {
        address_line_1 = "Berlin"
        city           = "Berlin"
        contact_type   = "PERSON"
        country_code   = "DE"
        email          = var.aws_billing_mails[0]
        first_name     = "Foo"
        last_name      = "Bar"
        zip_code       = "12345"
        phone_number   = "+49.123456789"
    }
}
```

then

```
resource "aws_route53domains_registered_domain" "domain" {
  
  for_each           = local.contact

  domain_name        = each.key
  auto_renew         = true
  transfer_lock      = true
  registrant_privacy = true
  admin_privacy      = true
  tech_privacy       = true

  registrant_contact {
    address_line_1 = each.value.address_line_1
    city           = each.value.city
    contact_type   = each.value.contact_type
    country_code   = each.value.country_code
    email          = each.value.email
    first_name     = each.value.first_name
    last_name      = each.value.last_name
    zip_code       = each.value.zip_code
    phone_number   = each.value.phone_number
  }

  admin_contact {
    address_line_1 = each.value.address_line_1
    city           = each.value.city
    contact_type   = each.value.contact_type
    country_code   = each.value.country_code
    email          = each.value.email
    first_name     = each.value.first_name
    last_name      = each.value.last_name
    zip_code       = each.value.zip_code
    phone_number   = each.value.phone_number
  }

  tech_contact {
    address_line_1 = each.value.address_line_1
    city           = each.value.city
    contact_type   = each.value.contact_type
    country_code   = each.value.country_code
    email          = each.value.email
    first_name     = each.value.first_name
    last_name      = each.value.last_name
    zip_code       = each.value.zip_code
    phone_number   = each.value.phone_number
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you always use same contact, then:

```
locals {
 
  domains = ["mydomain.com", "myotherdomain.com"]

  contact = {
    address_line_1 = "Berlin"
    city           = "Berlin"
    contact_type   = "PERSON"
    country_code   = "DE"
    email          = var.aws_billing_mails[0]
    first_name     = "Foo"
    last_name      = "Bar"
    zip_code       = "12345"
    phone_number   = "+49.123456789"
  }
}
```

then

```
resource "aws_route53domains_registered_domain" "my_domain" {

  for_each           = toset(local.domains) 

  domain_name        = each.key
  auto_renew         = true
  transfer_lock      = true
  registrant_privacy = true
  admin_privacy      = true
  tech_privacy       = true

  registrant_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }

  admin_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }

  tech_contact {
    address_line_1 = local.contact.address_line_1
    city           = local.contact.city
    contact_type   = local.contact.contact_type
    country_code   = local.contact.country_code
    email          = local.contact.email
    first_name     = local.contact.first_name
    last_name      = local.contact.last_name
    zip_code       = local.contact.zip_code
    phone_number   = local.contact.phone_number
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This reduces the number of lines drastically as I need to define 5 domains in terraform.

Comment: @msdundar No problem. The current `local.contact` allows you to have different contacts for different domains. If you are always using same ones, then you can make it even shorter.

Comment: I'm always using the same ones. It would be great if you could also add that to your answer so that I and all others can learn how to do that!

Comment: @msdundar Updated the answer. Locals is shorter now.